# Using Powershell to get Office 365 SMTP: email addresses

Tags: powershell

Found the exact script I need:

https://unlockpowershell.wordpress.com/2010/01/27/powershell-get-mailbox-display-smtp-addresses/

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited |Select-Object DisplayName,ServerName,PrimarySmtpAddress, @{Name=“EmailAddresses”;Expression={$_.EmailAddresses |Where-Object {$_.PrefixString -ceq “smtp”} | ForEach-Object {$_.SmtpAddress}}}
```

When I run this using Powershell5 against Office 365, "Email Addresses" is returned blank.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Email {space} Addresses" is blank? Is that accidental? Should it be blank - do you have secondary email addresses on the mailboxes returned from Get-Mailbox?

Comment: Yes, I mean EmailAddresses. All users have multiple smtp addresses that should be returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may have worked on Exchange 2007/2010, where the blog post says it was tested, but O365 mailboxes are a little different.

The `EmailAddresses` property of a mailbox object in O365 is an array list containing strings and they have no `PrefixString` property here. The issue is at this point

```
Where-Object {$_.PrefixString -ceq “smtp”}
```

Since `PrefixString` doesn't exist, you get blank results.

Instead, since the `EmailAddresses` array is just a bunch of strings, you can filter on those directly.

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Select-Object DisplayName,ServerName,PrimarySmtpAddress, @{Name=“EmailAddresses”;Expression={$_.EmailAddresses | Where-Object {$_ -clike “smtp*”}}}
```

Comment: `$_.PrefixString` returns a `$null` if the property doesn't exist. `Set-StrictMode -Version 5` would make it throw an exception that the property cannot be found, that might have shown the problem sooner